# Find out what writes to this address

Tags: memory, assembly

How to locate the assembly code that change the specific memory address?

For example:
Now:

ADDRESS     VALUE

0x730b54    1000

Then the value changed:

ADDRESS     VALUE

0x730b54    6000

I want know the assembly code that modified the value of this piece of memory. Could I do that?

Just like Cheat Engine's "Find out what writes to this address".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way would be with a debugger, set to break on writes to the address.

If you want something to do that monitoring and nothing else, it's possible, but the code is highly platform specific, so you'd need to tell us the platform you want to develop for before anybody can give much help.

I'd also note that even if the code you're monitoring is written in assembly language, there's no particular reason to write the monitoring code in assembly. Something like C or C++ works quite nicely for the task, although it does help (a lot) to have a fair amount of knowledge at the assembly language level. Even though you retrieve then in structs so C can use them, you still end up directly modifying the registers of the target process to debug it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply，platform is mac osx.